# not getting entire xml data into tableview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, xml-parsing

im parsing xml data into table view,here iam retrieving **question** and **answer** tags,problem occured in **question** tag only one question was displayed remaining questions not displayed ,this is the web service http://www.cmellc.com/DesktopModules/CaseChallenge/quiz.xml
this is the code i wrote

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
currentTag = elementName;

if ([currentTag isEqualToString:@"question"])
{
    model = [[ModelDataView alloc]init];
}

if([currentTag isEqualToString:@"answer"])
{
    model_2=[[Model2 alloc]init];
}  
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"question"])
{
    [dataControllerArray addObject:model];
}

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"answer"])
{
    [dataControllerArray2 addObject:model_2];
    model_2 = nil;
}

currentTag = nil;

}  
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
if ([currentTag isEqualToString:@"result"])
{
    model_2.result = string;
}

if ([currentTag isEqualToString:@"notes"])
{
    model_2.notes = string;
}

if ([currentTag isEqualToString:@"question"]) 
{
    model.question = string;
}

}
```

this is code for tableview methods

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
   static NSString *cellIdentifier2 = @"cell2";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
if(tableView.tag==2)
  {
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
Model2 *obj=[modelController.dataControllerArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *res=obj.result;
   cell.textLabel.text=res;
  return cell;
  }
     else   if(tableView.tag==1)
{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier2] autorelease];
    }

    ModelDataView *obj=[modelController.dataControllerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *res=obj.question;
UIWebView *_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 190)];
[self.view addSubview:_webView];
        CGRect frame = _webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 190;
        _webView.frame = frame;
  [_webView loadHTMLString:res baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:res]];
  return cell;
    }
}
```

thank you for helping me

Comment: What's in `dataControllerArray` when you're finished parsing?  What do your data source methods look like for your table?

Comment: im just allocating dataControllerArray nothing is there

Comment: in tableview cellforRowAtIndexPath im assigning the Model object to that array

Comment: Before I read this more thoroughly, are you sure you have `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returning more than one count? Have you debugged this as a parsing problem or a datasource problem?

Comment: i have checked it is a parsing problem

Comment: i thought object added once in the dataControllerArray